# Safari extension modifying to an iframe within main page

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

Hi I've wrote simple Safari extension to display QR code with url to currently visiting website..This is part of code where I am appending the code to page..

```
document.body.insertBefore(qrdisplay, document.body.firstChild);
   qrdisplay.appendChild(img);
```

All is wokring, but what sucks is, the code appends too to an iframe content..Actually nasty problem if every site contains facebook like box and lot of other crap:D Can I somehow append the element only to main body?When I would use some kind of "body child of body" selector it wouldnt work..It simply cant as there are two independent DOMs?Am I right?

Thanks for your advice, I hope you understand to my problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check if `window === window.top` before running your appending code.

Comment: Yes..:)Thanks..Accepted..Not yet, I cant:D